# How do i have OneToOne relationship between any two fields of different models in Django?

Tags: python, django

```
class HmsMedicine(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    medicine_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(max_length=6)

class HmsBilling(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    regid = models.ForeignKey(HmsPatient, db_column='regid')
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(HmsMedicine, db_column='medicine')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to have the values of `price` field in the `rate` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HmsBilling(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    regid = models.ForeignKey(HmsPatient, db_column='regid')
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(HmsMedicine, db_column='medicine')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.ForeignKey(HmsMedicine, db_column='price')

hms = HmsBilling.objects.select_related().get(id=5)
hms.rate
```

this will give you the price for the billing with id = 5 (see [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for reference on select related)

better:

```
class HmsBilling(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(HmsMedicine)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

hms = HmsBilling.objects.select_related().get(id=5)
hms.medicine.price
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to have the values of Price in my Billing Template. But the problem is price field belongs to some other model.

Comment: select_related() retrieves the related objects of the Billing class, so you can easily access your foreign keys... let me fix the answer a bit :)